# How many web-push Subscription objects should I keep in database?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, architecture, notifications, web-push

I'm new to web-push notifications and I've created a web app handy for both PC and mobile. I created notifications and due to limited storage (free 512 MB in Mongo Atlas), I need wanted to know how many Push Subscription objects should I store in database to send notifications to?

Scenario 1:
if a user uses 2 devices both will get float notifications, but if he discards one device, or changes a browser, the older browser entries will become useless and take space in database.

Scenario 2:
if user uses multiple devices I keep the record of the latest device/browser, but this will keep him from getting notifications in his older devices.

Which one will be optimum?

structure of sub object:

```
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/eDeNLoS7m7M:APA91bF7HHZ6_hujpm47yuikjMNVx247fuLAAkxZbnj_cF2ODmqo-UgU-dKGKYXwNbdq0LS-Ns8eWFFmv52uzQO6agTcEjGMifpfomPwpm8VHEUKxyX3ms7J1aLi34gzKXgdxL8AiAvo",
"expirationTime":null,
"keys": {
  "p256dh":"BBDbLS_UBcaDIEgtK9rzCLYRLzYyrC_f9GGPTymPIT79Wpsn_k9x_vpPEa13DOR5ZZ-ohT-YX4aBHloYx0WpdPE",
  "auth":"f1UCyrwzENKsKec7qa9Myg"
        }
}
```

Mongoose schema of collection:

```
const pushNotificationsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'User'},
    subobjects: {type:[Object], default: []},
    time: String
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell me those aren't your actual API keys?

Comment: If they are, I'm not sure editing them out will help as people can review the question history - you may need to delete.  Can anyone please advise?

Comment: no those arent the api keys :p

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of trade-offs:

1. If keeping your app free is more important, then let that drive design decisions, even if it means having a less useful / functional system.
2. If having better and more useful / functional system is more important, then either accept the costs or work on ways of minimizing the cost without impacting functionality.  This might include functionality that looks for orphan records/devices, and deletes them.

The danger with 2 is that if it's not useful no one will use it.

Comment: okay. Ive set the limit of 3 push objects per user. The con is if user subscribes from same browser and same machine twice, he'll get the notification twice. Should this be a fine choice?

Comment: Can't you do a check to see if it's the same device?
Can you provide the user with any way of "managing" their subscriptions (devices/objects)?

Comment: How do I do that? I cant recognise a device from the subscription object right? The values are unique every time

Comment: Well, do some research into the technology you are using and what data you can reasonably expect to get access to.  At a bare minimum you should have a UserAgent string if your solution is web-based.

Comment: Okay. I'll read about UserAgent. Thanks for help @Adrian . Really appreciate your help :-)